# Failed close review audit - how was this poor question chosen?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I came across what is in my option, a poorly composed question: [Facebook Messenger Bot config issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628890/facebook-messenger-bot-config-issue) during review. I am surprised this question drew upvotes, it's more or less summed up as "what is going on with facebook?" and the accepted answer is (again, more or less) "try again tomorrow."

I can't understand how this question was not slammed immediately and closed out, and even more so why it was [selected for an audit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12067136) - which I failed.

Is there an automatic process which just selects questions with a certain number of upvotes and batches them in the audit queue?

Comment: If it's any consolation - the question is now closed...

Comment: Whenever a service breaks, people run here and post questions about it. Others seem to regard those questions as bug reports, and vote them up in an attempt to increase visibility. They also tend to post tons of "me, too" non-answers, which makes these a joy to deal with.