# Failed review audit by choosing to close question that is already closed

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I failed a Close Votes review audit yesterday (2016-04-29):   https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12056572

I chose to close the question, but I failed. It says it should be left open.

However, [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628890/facebook-messenger-bot-config-issue) was actually already closed by a moderator a few days ago (2016-04-25), so I'm very surprised. Why am I wrong choosing to close a question that a mod has already closed?

It turns out that somebody else failed another audit on the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12067136
and there's a story about it:
[Failed close review audit - how was this poor question chosen?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321679/failed-close-review-audit-how-was-this-poor-question-chosen)

Comment: Possibly bad audit since the score is positive.

Comment: Interesting - I thought closing it should have either removed it from the queue or at the very least made closing it a valid action... *sighs*

Comment: @JonClements you didn't close it until after Pang already failed the audit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I closed it on the 25th - 4 days before Pang failed it on the 29th

Comment: @JonClements huh that's really weird.  [Pang's audit has conflicting dates in the timeline.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36628890/timeline)

Comment: I remember Shog saying that we should blame caching...

Comment: Uh... I guess my entire timeline argument is invalid then since the dates are totally messed up.

Comment: Actually - I think you're right @ryanyuyu. It was enqueued as a close vote audit on Apr 18th (presumably with a known successful response to be leave open) - my closing it on the 25th would have just stopped it being queued again for that reason - not invalidated the queued audit whicih Pang unfortunately hit upon yesterday.

Comment: @JonClements so because it had already been selected to be used as an audit back when it was eligible it didn't matter that the post was no longer eligible when Pang came upon it?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm not 100% sure, but I think I've seen something similar before stating that the audit queue isn't in sync with the related post's state.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is just a normal case of a bad audit being removed as an audit after the fact.  The [post's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36628890/timeline) tells the full story:

By its first day, the question had a score of +5 and was unclosed which makes it eligible as a "known good" audit.  The timeline show that it was quickly queued up to be used as a future "known good" audit.  The [top timestamp of the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36628890/timeline#review_12056572) shows the time it was added to the review system as an audit.

Several days later, it finally got some downvotes and a moderator (Jon Clements) closed the question possibly after seeing the meta post that you linked to.  And finally, you stumbled upon previously stored audit, which fills out the bottom timestamp on the audit in the timeline.

So the timing is just all messed up, but at the time it was a poorly chosen audit.  Now it's no longer eligible to be an audit, closed, and on its way to deletion with one delete vote.

Comment: This happens when users skip the audits. Normally they get created and completed moments apart. But if someone skips the audit, it can sometimes linger around in the system for days before getting used again, especially if subsequent users keep skipping it too.

Comment: So would it then be too burdensome to re-check audit questions when they get skipped, before re-queueing them?  There are many reasons that a reviewer may skip a review, but skipping an audit question *can* be a sign that it's not such a good audit case.

Comment: If this is *normal*, then we need to change the audit system some more.