# Immediately drop skipped audits and do not reuse them

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

A [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322106/failed-review-audit-by-choosing-to-close-question-that-is-already-closed?cb=1#comment339126_322116) of Animuson piqued my interest about this:

> This happens when users skip the audits. Normally they get created and
>   completed moments apart. But if someone skips the audit, it can
>   sometimes linger around in the system for days before getting used
>   again, especially if subsequent users keep skipping it too. –
>   animuson♦ yesterday

According to this, audits that are created can under some circumstances linger unused in the system for several days. That means that, like in the question this comment was a reply to, users get served audits where the system *should* know that they are invalid. This adds a layer of frustration and divination to the process that is very very hard to shake off.

Imagine yourself, encountering a "known good" audit on a question that is closed. You see the question and think it should be closed. You click through and see it already is, by a moderator no less. Now, unless you had special tools for detecting this, you could reasonably assume that this is a "known bad" audit.

Literally nothing but careless voting without looking twice will get you past such an audit.

I therefore propose that all audits are used only once, even when the reviewer who got served these skipped.

Alternatively (if this is too hard to implement) a check could be made every time a stored audit is used again after being skipped, to see if it was still eligible to be used as one, and invalidate it if that's no longer the case.

Comment: I skip audits when I don't recognize that they're audits but the subject matter is outside my area of expertise.  Often, I can spot an audit, but not always, and I have no hesitation about skipping what I don't know about.  That could waste perfectly good audits.  Whether that matters is a separate issue — maybe there are enough candidate audit questions that it isn't a problem to waste them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I always recognize audits because I only review [tag:c++] but audits are usually for another language.

Comment: Some way to revoke the audit when they SHOULD be cancelled (closing "good" audit question, opening and upvoting a bad one) would be much better. This would be a good temporary workaround for the time when skip is the best answer to bad audits.

Comment: The need to skip an audit suggests it is a poor audit to begin with. Audits shouldn't be tricky borderline cases, nor should you need any special technical knowledge to pass them. For the 255th time: fix the audit generation. It is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of this can't we just have a sanity check on the audit before it is served?  When the audit is selected but before it is served up to the user is should query the current state.  If that current state does not meet the audit criteria then it should be removed from the audit pool and a new one selected.  This should stop your scenario from happening as it would know it is closed and not use it as a known good audit.

I do not think skipping an audit should be used to disqualify it.  We have no idea why the user skipped it.  It could be it was a borderline question so they decided to do nothing, it could be there was a picture of a cat and it scared them off, or Tim Post could have lost his keys again.  Skip to me does not say anything about the quality of the post but more that the user just does not want to deal with it.